How to draw a ROC curve given estimated probability that a unit is positive and actual observed class?
Assume that a classification model fitted to data available to you has provided for each statistical unit a probability $P(+|x)$ that the unit is positive. The following table shows all available units, the predicted probability for each unit, and the true observed classes.
















Unit
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8


P(+|x)
0.95
0.87
0.85
0.85
0.76
0.53
0.43
0.25


Actual class
+
-
-
+
-
+
-
+



(a) Draw the ROC curve for this model.
(b) Do you think this is a good model? Briefly justify your answer.

I'm stuck with this question. I figured that I can use $P(+|x)$ as an estimate for $1 - \mbox{specificity}$ for each point, but I can't see how to estimate sensitivity.
